# How to use tensorflow in blender?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, blender

My setup:

Blender 2.8.2
Python 3.7.4

I want to implement tensorflow in blender. I try it with pip, but I get these:
How I can install tensorflow to use it in a pyhton scripft for blender.

```
 main(["install","tensorflow"])
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/6a/9669836f813b73fe5abf5e9f118ccc9b7fb060f02789d385825b0943f9c8/tensorflow-2.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/00/3df031b3ecd5444d572141321537080b40c1c25e1caa3d86cdd12e5e919c/wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.7.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/58/0aa6fb779dc69cfc811df3398fcbeaeefbf18561b6e36b185df0782781cc/absl_py-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/19/404708a7e54ad2798907210462fd950c3442ea51acc8790f3da48d2bee8b/opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gast==0.3.3 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/84/759f5dd23fec8ba71952d97bcc7e2c9d7d63bdc582421f3cd4be845f0c98/gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/03/13dde6512ad7b4557eb792fbcf0c653af6076b81e5941d36ec61f7ce6028/astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.82\2.82\python\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.17.0)
Collecting tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/83/179c8f76e5716030cc3ee9433721161cfcc1d854e9ba20c9205180bb100a/tensorboard-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/ed/5853ec0ae380cba4588eab1524e18ece1583b65f7ae0e97321f5ff9dfd60/tensorflow_estimator-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Read prefs: C:\Users\danny\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\config\userpref.blend
    AL lib: (EE) SetChannelMap: Failed to match front-center channel (2) in channel map
    found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\python
    Warning: class ANIM_OT_set_keyingset contains a property which should be an annotation!
    C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py:712
        assign as a type annotation: ANIM_OT_set_keyingset.type
    Warning: class V_OT_set contains a property which should be an annotation!
    C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py:712
        assign as a type annotation: V_OT_set.type
    unknown argument, loading as file: -c
Error: Cannot read file 'C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jd4_2fc1\termcolor\-c': No such file or directory
    Error: argument has no '.blend' file extension, not using as new file, exiting! C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jd4_2fc1\termcolor\-c
    Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
        mod = __import__(module_name)
      File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\scripts\addons\verge3d\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from pluginUtils.log import printLog
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pluginUtils'
    Reloading .babylon exporter
    register_class(...):
    Warning: 'blendi' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
    register_class(...):
    Warning: 'anime' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
    register_class(...):
    Warning: 'blendo' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
    
    Blender quit
    
    ----------------------------------------
1

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jd4_2fc1\termcolor\
```

I already tried to update my setup tools.
Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will upgrade pip and install tensorflow inside the site-packages of Blender's Python (Blender 2.82 has Python 3.7.4).n
This is the folder where tensorflow will be installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\python\lib\site-packages\
```

Press Start, write cmd and press the right button on Command Prompt, choose 'Run As Administrator'.
To write in this area you need the administrator privileges, that's why you're opening the terminal as administrator.

1--> Upgrade pip in Blender
If you didn't change the path during the Blender installation, for Blender 2.82 it should be this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\python\bin"
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

You've done.
To check everything is OK, launch Blender from the terminal, in this way you can see the output in the terminal.
Open Blender:

```
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\blender.exe"
```

Once Blender is opened go to Scripting Layout and create a new text file and write this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

The first time you're importing the module take a little bit.
In the terminal, the last line should be something like this:

```
tf.Tensor(970.3253, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```